# SSRS dynamic group expression needs to be null if a parameter is null

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, grouping

I have an SSRS report that I am doing dynamic grouping on. Regular grouping on a field name that is provided through a report parameter is working with no problems.

The problem that I am having is that I want to avoid the grouping if the parameter is null.

I tried what this article suggested to use (checking for null in the IIF statement) but it isn't working for me:
http://www.optimusbi.com/2012/10/12/dynamic-grouping-ssrs/

**NOT WORKING:**

Setting GROUP_3 report parameter to NULL and checking for null in the grouping expression.

```
=IIF(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value is Nothing,1,Fields(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value).Value)
```

**Result:**
The IIF expression doesn't seem to be evaluating the null value properly. I get this as the result...

> The Group expression for the grouping ‘GROUP_3’ contains an error: The
>   expression references the field '', which does not exist in the Fields
>   collection. Expressions can only refer to fields within the current
>   dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.
>   Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
>   (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

I also tried setting the parameter to 'blank' and this but I get the same error message.

```
 =IIF(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value = "",1,Fields(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value).Value)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Iif()` call evaluates all parameters passed to it. So when GROUP_3 doesn't have a value, you're trying to reference a non-existent member of the Fields collection in the third parameter of `Iif()`.

It's possible (though ugly) to work around this with another embedded `IIF()` thusly:

```
IIF(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value is Nothing,1,Fields(IIF(Parameters!GROUP_3.Value is Nothing,"VALID COLUMN NAME",Parameters!GROUP_3.Value)).Value)
```

In case it isn't obvious, you need to replace "VALID COLUMN NAME" with a column name from your dataset. Doesn't matter which column it is as long as it's always in the dataset. This means if GROUP_3 is nothing it's using a valid column name reference in parameter three just to get around the error. The `IIF()` call will still default it to '1' and the code should behave as you desire.

Comment: I already tried this and it doesn't work how I want it to. Adding a blank column in my sp isn't a choice since I am working with existing stored procedures. I tried adding a blank field into the dataset but i get the same error message. (The expression references the field '', which does not exist in the Fields collection)

Comment: Yep. I was just looking at something like that. This is the kind of bad stuff I was trying to avoid. BUT it is a solution for now.